# Boot manager is deleted every time I restart Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd

About a month ago, I upgraded Windows 10 to build 1607. After that, every time I restart my laptop it says "No Boot Device Found" and I have to recover my boot partition using startup repair. I know some of the known issues of build 1607, and one of them is deleting partitions without asking. But I couldn't find the solution. I use SSD as my main drive and HDD along with it.

Here's how my partitions are configured:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when switching to SSD a while ago, a bios update solved my issues.

Comment: I updated the bios. However, it didn't solve the issue.